# Python - Get current user folder when launching project remotely

Tags: python, jenkins, remote-access

I have a program i am launching from a Jenkins server.

I created an exe using pyinstaller and installed it on two computers. and then Jenkins calls them both.

At first i used **os.path.expanduser('~')** to get the user path but it returned

```
"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile"
```

After i tried to just get the user name using **os.environ['USERPROFILE']**
still got:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile"
```

Lastly i found a different solution that didnt require os module and tried:

```
import ctypes.wintypes
CSIDL_PERSONAL = 5       # My Documents
SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0   # Get current, not default value

buf= ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(ctypes.wintypes.MAX_PATH)
ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(None, CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 
SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf)

print(buf.value)
```

That gave no value back in my log value.

If i run the exe locally, all the value return back normally. 
The batch command i run is

```
start /wait C:\JenkinsResources\MarinaMain.exe
```

So im drawing a blank as how i can get this program to find the user folder of the computer it is on, when i call it remotely.

Comment: Is it possible your two slave computers run the job as SYSTEM and not a normal logged in user and that this prevents the expected results from being returned? If so, I believe you can go to Windows Services in the control panel and have it run under a different user.

Comment: I tried using psexec and ran the command to run as system. Got the same path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get this to work I first downloaded the Windows Power Shell plugin.
After the restart I used the command:

```
$PCAndUserName = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username

$UserName = [string]$PCAndUserName
$UserName = $UserName.split("\\")[-1]
$UserName = $UserName -replace ".{1}$"
$UserName
```

That gave me the name of the current user on the computer regardless of if I launch remotely with Jenkins.